# one log per day on a /etc/init/*.conf unix service

Tags: unix, logging, service, centos

I have a service saved in /etc/init/API.conf that starts my NodeJS server on startup.

It works great without issue, but the log file always has the same name, and get really big over time.

I'd like to have one log per day, so having a dynamic filename based on the date.

**Here is my service:**

```
description "API"
author      "Julien L - http://www.gamify.io/"
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[345]
stop on shutdown
script
    export HOME="/root"
    cd /home/gitbuffer/Gamify/
    exec node /home/gitbuffer/Gamify/main.js -online true -timeout 20000 -threads 128 -debug_mode false -process_emails false -mongo_remote true -mongo_server xxxxxxx.objectrocket.com -mongo_login xxx -mongo_password xxxxxxxxxxx -mongo_port 15110 > error_log &
end script
```

All the output from the server goes into error_log, using  **> error_log &**

How can I change that to have the filename of the log having its name based on the current date? ("error_log_05_07_14" for example)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two solutions to this problem.

1. Use a command to get the current date (in whatever format you want) in the startup script and use that value in the filename in the redirection.
2. Set up configuration for your application in something like [logrotate](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/) and have it do the rotation (on whatever schedule you want) for you.